# Vlookup and paste the entire row-Applying for entire sheet alternatively

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to Vlookup a value and copy the entire row that matches

For eg: if I am searching for `id=1234` in sheet A

```
1234 ABC DEF HIJ
```

The Vlookup should return the entire values.

I am trying to apply this formula in alternate rows of a sheet-The look up value is always in Column A (in the row just above).

Is this possible?

I am a novice in Excel VBA and any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you need these values for? I mean, you want to put them into one cell all together?

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to store your data in alternate rows, it makes lookups very difficult. It's better to keep all the data together with no gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a separate VLookup for each piece of data

```
=Vlookup($A1,Sheet1!$A:$C,Column(Sheet1!B:B),false)
```

If you use this code in the first cell and copy it across it will give you the correct formula for each piece of data.

I have assumed that the data you are searching for is in cell A1 of the current sheet and that the data you are searching is in Sheet1 between Columns A and C. You will need to modify these values if you are doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of an item use the [Match Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel) instead of Vlookup.

```
position = WorksheetFunction.Match("1234", Worksheets("yoursheet").Columns(1), 0)
```

Now you can use the position to copy the entire row like

```
Worksheets("yoursheet").Rows(position).Copy
```